# is there any replacement of Access?

Tags: linux, ms-access, open-source

I am a programmer, and my father uses Access to collect the patients information (my father is a doctor),

He wants me to teach him how to use it.

I don't like Access (I'm a linux guy), and I cannot find any replacement of it. Do you guys know of any? (it must be easy enough for my father to use)

Comment: That sounds exactly like what access was intended for if you ask me. It's when he starts saying he wants people to be able to send him messages and look at their histories over the web that you want to suggest switching to other technologies. A friend of mine started a pool cleaning business and to show my support I write him a little access app to help him with billing. It keeps track of his clients addresses, lets him add charges throughout the month and then lets him print out invoices. It's Access but I'm still pretty proud of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access is not always the monster it is made out to be. A poorly coded database in any application or language is a poorly coded database. Access' dominance of the market at a critical time led to more people coming across a higher ratio of poorly designed databases.
There's a great deal of support out there for Access users and programmers too. I particularly like [Access World Forums](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/index.php). As [ilivewithian said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867760/is-there-any-replacement-of-access/867793#867793), if you're not happy telling him about it, get someone else to.

If however you are keen to take on the role of tutor to your dad (and I can see the attraction - a chance to give something back, perhaps), then I would suggest a web-based database interface. Unlike [Oli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867760/is-there-any-replacement-of-access/867783#867783), I have no experience of Django, but I would recommend [Dabble](http://dabbledb.com/) or [blist](http://www.blist.com/). (Blist is particularly good at handling images, Dabble is better at flexible report formats, though neither is as good at reports as Access, IMHO).

Comment: Just a thought - does storing the data in a web-based application conflict with patient confidentiality?

Comment: It will only be a confidentiality issue if the data is public or the site is cracked.

Comment: Would you be happy to have your private medical data in an on-line database, which may or may not be coded by a novice (Dad)?
If you are going to do anything like this, at least do it on an inward only facing webserver. There's no reason Dad should have to get at it from home.

Second, perhaps there is a package out there that you can get. It's probably more cost effective than the cost of having Dr. Dad do the coding himself.

Comment: According to HIPPA, you have to have data in a compliant location. I wouldn't want a Dabble employee having access to my medical records (If they are in HIPPA compliance, they take on the responsibility of their employees.).

Comment: The web site will only be used in hospital, and be accessed by internal user(doctors) only.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe you need to be a bit more pragmatic about this.

I'm not a fan of Access either, but if your father already understands it and he already has the system in place, you need to ask the question, why change? If it aint broke don't try to fix it.

You may find that a few simple changes in the existing system gives your father everything he needs, it'll save you a whole lot of time and means you don't need to retrain your father.

Answer (score 8):

What about [OpenOffice - Base](http://www.openoffice.org/)?

Answer (score 8):

Your father wants you to teach him how to use access but you're a linux guy and don't like access.
Access isn't the problem here
I don't think you and your father a good fit for this.

Get someone else to teach him how to use Access

Comment: Perhaps, but there is also the question whether he really wants "the" Access (thing from MS), or "access", as in something that does what Access does. This is not nitpicking, just an observation; for most people "excel" is the noun meaning spreadsheet app.

So it is possible that an alternative would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the natural successor to Access is a simple web-interface database system.

They're simple enough to create in a billion different ways but I would seriously suggest trying Django (because you'll find its admin area does 90% of the real work for you in this case)

Comment: I'm learning it now , and it looks hard.. maybe I will try to teach it to my father...

Answer (score 2):

[FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/) Inc. is subsidiary of Apple.  It runs on Mac OS X as well as Windows (whereas MS Access only runs on Windows).  Many people claim FileMaker is easier to use than MS Access.  Sounds like FileMaker might be the perfect solution for you! (although I do agree with [ilivewithian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867760/is-there-any-replacement-of-access/867793#867793))

There's also Sun's counterpart to MS Access in [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)/[StarOffice](http://www.staroffice.org/get.html) called [BASE](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) (someone already mentioned this), which is also cross-platform compatible.

Comment: +1 FileMaker is incredible. It took me a few days to get started, but once I became familiar with it, I found FileMaker to be the most intuitive and easy-to-use database product that I have worked with. Note that [FileMaker Bento](http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/) may be more suitable for someone without a deep technical background as it's intended to be an inexpensive personal database product. I haven't tried it myself, however.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than develop his own record keeping application he would probably be better off purchasing an already developed system from one of the numerous medical record system vendors.  He'll get a better application and have people he can call on for support.  Plus there are all of the legal issues about medical record storage and access.  A vendor will have worked out those problems already.

That having been said there are many other file based databased systems out there: http://www.google.com/search?q=file+based+database

I haven't used any of them so I can't make a recommendation.

Of course, there's always the various enterprise databases (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc...) as well.  Of those SQL Server is probably the easiest to learn for a newbie.  Since there's no 64 bit version of Access I'm starting to see people replace Access with SQL Server Express (free!) for small applications that need to run on 64 bit windows.

Comment: How do you replace the front end creation tools in Access with SQL Server Express?

Comment: Uhhh, use Access as the front-end? At least the data would be safe in a real DB server.

Comment: You could use whatever language/library/platform you're most comfortable with to write a client to use as the front end.  For example, you could very easily whip up a small simple UI with a few tables and forms in .NET using WPF.  It's very straight forward to get a .NET app to "talk" to a database.

Comment: gets harder fast when you start added data validation!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Viravis now for more than 6 months in a multi-language organization with several projects and I find it very good. It's not only easy to build (I am a beginner) but they give also very good support!

Answer (score 1):

[Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html) ist a very good alternative for Access if one used Access as a database frontend and programmed with VBA (Visual Basic fro Applications). One can reuse a lot of code written for Access and create forms and reports easily.

So for a VB or VBA programmer, who wants to use the own knowledge under Linux, Gambas is a wonderful solution.

Answer (score 0):

No first hand experience, but you can try out OpenOffic.org Database. Or, you may teach your Dad to use the MySQL GUI tool.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the database structure is the toughest part for most. Creating a simple form or report is not that tough either. As far as being a users (data entry, reports, etc.) is probably easier than most applications. You also have all the searching and sorting capabilities; why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

[Viravis](http://www.viravis.com) may be an online alternative to the access database. You should better to check it out if it fit your need.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows and simple data, I would use Excel, so I think Open Office should be ok. Unless your father has a hospital, it will probably fit... Or you can do some programming, take embedded database like Firebird and write something on your own, say - in Java?